# Retrieving aggregate data from multiple indexes in Sphinx

Tags: php, cakephp, sphinx

I've been playing around a lot with Sphinx lately - and it's a pretty fantastic tool. However, it is proving to be a little challenging to configure correctly and make it do what I want.

Let's say I have three tables in my database: people, orders, comments; which I then build three separate indexes around.

Using the PHP API provided by Sphinx, I am able to connect to the server and execute a simple $Query() command and it is indeed searching all the indexes.

Now, this is the part I'm confused about:

The result set returns an array for each index, which is then sorted by it's weighting. So the array would have three keys:

0 [people], 1 [orders], and 2 [comments].

What I'm looking for is **one aggregate array** containing results from all indexes sorted by weight, which will make it easier for me to then paginate the results later on.

I'm using CakePHP. I'm aware of the existing plugins, etc., that the community has made available, but none of them seem to be able to search across multiple tables - only a single model.